# Passing URL of local image as a prop to component in React

Tags: reactjs

So I wish to display multiple cards on my page which comprise of a `ProjectCard` component being used multiple times. The `ProjectCard` component is called three times for now in the `ProjectSection` Component. The `ProjectSection` component is as follows:

```js
import React from "react";
import ProjectCard from "./ProjectCard";

function ProjectSection() {
  const projects = [
    {
      title: "Project 1",
      imageUrl: "../assets/free-stock-image-1.jpg",
      expect: "This is my project about...",
    },
    {
      title: "Project 2",
      imageUrl: "../assets/free-stock-image-2.jpg",
      expect: "This is my project about...",
    },
    {
      title: "Project 3",
      imageUrl: "../assets/free-stock-image-3.jpg",
      expect: "This is my project about...",
    },
  ];
  return (
    <div className="container text-center my-5">
      <h1>
        My <span className="text-info">Projects</span>
      </h1>
      <div className="lead">I build products. Just like this website</div>
      <div className="row my-5 pt-3">
        {projects.map((project) => (
          <div className="col-12 col-md-4 py-2">
            <ProjectCard
              title={project.title}
              excerpt={project.excerpt}
              imageUrl={project.imageUrl}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="my-5">
        <a href="/" className="text-dark text-right">
          <h5>
            See my projects
            <i className="fas fa-arrow-right align-middle"></i>
          </h5>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProjectSection;
```

The `projects` array consists of objects which comprise of the Title, the URL and the Excerpt of the card.

The `ProjectCard` component is as follows:

```js
import React from "react";

function ProjectCard(props) {
  const { title, excerpt, imageUrl } = props;
  return (
    <div className="card shadow h-100">
      <img className="card-img-top" src={imageUrl} alt="Project" />
      <div className="card-body">
        <h4 className="card-title">{title}</h4>
        <p className="card-text">{excerpt}</p>
        <a href="/" className="stretched-link"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProjectCard;
```

In the `ProjectCard` component, for the `img` tag, I wish to pass the imageUrl prop taken from the `projects` array in the `ProjectSection`.

The File Composition of my project is as follows:

[image: File Composition]

Where the `Assets` folder consists of all my image files in it.

How do I go on about it?

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: @Dominik, when you are importing images in the React components, you need to use either of these two methods right? The first being importing the image as a name from the source and the second being using the 'require' method like if my image is in the assets folder, I've got to do, src = {require("../assets/imageName.jpg")}. So, say my issue is, the URL in the require tag, I wish to import it via a prop as mentioned in the problem above. How do I go on about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

Turns out, these are the changes I made.

1. In my projects array, instead of passing the Url as a string to my `imageUrl`, I passed the string to the `require()` method, which in turn comprised of the `imageUrl`

```js
const projects = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Project 1",
      imageUrl: require("../assets/images/free-stock-image-1.jpg"),
      excerpt: "This is my project about...",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Project 2",
      imageUrl: require("../assets/images/free-stock-image-2.jpg"),
      excerpt: "This is my project about...",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "Project 3",
      imageUrl: require("../assets/images/free-stock-image-3.jpg"),
      excerpt: "This is my project about...",
    },
  ];
```

2. In the receiving component `ProjectCard`, the require methods returns an object. To utilise the image in the object, simply add .default to the prop as:

```js
import React from "react";

function ProjectCard(props) {
  const { title, excerpt, imageUrl } = props;
  return (
    <div className="card shadow h-100">
      <img className="card-img-top" src={imageUrl.default} alt="Project" />
      <div className="card-body">
        <h4 className="card-title">{title}</h4>
        <p className="card-text">{excerpt}</p>
        <a href="/" className="stretched-link"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProjectCard;
```

That solved my query!

Answer (score 2):

When you map through the `projects` the `ProjectSection` component, the props you are providing to each `ProjectCard` are incorrect.

Currently:

`<ProjectCard title={projects.title} excerpt={projects.excerpt} imageUrl={projects.imageUrl} />`

Should be:

`<ProjectCard title={project.title} excerpt={project.excerpt} imageUrl={project.imageUrl} />`

You can also just spread the `project` into the `ProjectCard` props:

`<ProjectCard {...project} />`

Comment: That's not the issue actually, I mean I changed it to project.excerpt alright, but what I want to do is, I want to add images in my react app with the help of require method, like src = {require("../assets/imageName.jpg")} but the URL in the require field, I wish to pass this as a prop from the projects array present in the ProjectSection component. How do I implement that?